# Django - How to filter purchased book by user

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have created a model where a user is allowed to purchase a book. The book being purchased was already recognized but when the user visits the content of the book, the following error occurs: get() returned more than one Purchase_Book -- it returned 2!

I already tried to tweak the codes but to no avail.

Here are my models and their connection to each other.

```
class Book(models.Model):
      # some book info

      def __str__(self):
          return self.title

      def get_absolute_url(self):
         return reverse('book-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

      @property
      def pages(self):
          return self.page_set.all()
```

*the content of the book*

```
class Page(models.Model):
    # some pdf files to upload

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('page-detail',
                   kwargs={
                       'book_slug': self.book.slug,
                       'page_slug': self.slug
                   })
```

*the models to be able to filter users who can access the contents of the book.*

```
class Purchase_Book(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    selected_Book = models.ManyToManyField(Book)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

class Customer(models.Model):
       user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       service_Type = models.ForeignKey(Purchase_Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

      def __str__(self):
         return self.user.email
```

*Here's my latest views.py, where I am filtering the user who can access the content of the book.*

```
class PageDetailView(NeverCacheMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, generic.View):

def get(self, request, book_slug, page_slug, *args, **kwargs):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, slug=book_slug)
    page = get_object_or_404(Page, slug=page_slug)
    purchased = get_object_or_404(Purchase_Book)
    user_membership = get_object_or_404(Customer, user=request.user)
    user_membership_type = user_membership.service_Type.selected_Book

    user_allowed = purchased.selected_Book.all()

    context = {'object': None}
    if user_allowed.filter(selected_Book=user_membership_type).exists():
        context = {'object': page}
    return render(request, "catalog/page_detail.html", context)
```

I'm still a beginner. I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error is for following line:

```
purchased = get_object_or_404(Purchase_Book)
```

It will throw error if multiple Purchased_Book is created. Ideally you need to provide a condition(or parameter) to get the actual object, ie `get_object_or_404(Purchase_Book, pk=1)`.

By the way, you can remove that line and get the purchased books for a particular Customer like this:

```
user_membership = get_object_or_404(Customer, user=request.user)
purchased = user_membership.service_Type
```

Also, I don't think following lines are necessary at all(explanation in code comments):

```
user_membership_type = user_membership.service_Type.selected_Book  # getting current user books

user_allowed = purchased.selected_Book.all()  # getting current user books

context = {'object': None}
if user_allowed.filter(selected_Book=user_membership_type).exists():  # comparing books ? Why? You can remove that, because you are already getting current user books. 
# if there is a relation between page and user, you should put logic for that here instead of current one
```

### Update

Some thing like this should work:

```
if purchased.selected_Book.filter(pk=page.book.pk).exists()
   context = {'object': page}
```

Comment: sorry for being idiot, but i tried the condition - if user_allowed: context = {'object': page}.. the user can access all books content even he/she not purchased it.

Comment: I am using comparing to filter the book that a user can only access. so that if a user visits the page content of the books, the code will detect if he/she purchased the book that he is trying to visit the content and it will render the context "Page" or "None". ..

Comment: @GiranyxPornasdoro please see the update section of my answer

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I've been dealing with this for sometime now, Thank you for answering my questions.